# How could I have a successful pop - up of dialog box?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

My aim is to have my modal dialog box pop up on click. However, I receive this error every time I execute:

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem

May I have some direction on where I am going wrong with this?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { myActions } from './actions/my.actions';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
class LoadTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            Search: "Search",
            visible: false
        }
        this.doSearch = this.doSearch.bind(this);
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.runstuff = this.runstuff(this);

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getstuff() 
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.results.response || [], <--IT shows in the error that it breaks here.
                    visible: false
                })
            });
    }

    doSearch(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
        console.log("Search");
    }

    handleShow() {
        this.setState({ visible: true });
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({ visible: false });
    }

    runstuff() {

    }
    render() {
        const { data, Search } = this.state;  
         return data.length > 0 ? (
            <div className="row row-centered">
                <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-centered">
                    <div id="Search" className="row col-xs-5 col-lg-2">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input className='form-control' type="text" placeholder="Search" name="Search" value={Search} onChange={this.doSearch} autoFocus />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>stuff</td>
                                <td>Start</td>
                                <td>End</td>
                                <td>Status</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        data.map((dt) => {
                            return (
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{dt.name}</td>
                                    <td>{dt.stuff}</td>
                                    <td>{dt.start}</td>
                                    <td>{dt.end}</td>
                                    { dt.status ?
                                        <td>
                                            <div className="alert alert-success" role="alert"></div>
                                        </td>
                                   :                                      
                                        <td>
                                            <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
                                        </td>
                                    }
                                    <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.runStuff}>Run Stufff</button></td>
                                    <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.displayLog}><View Stuff</button></td>
                                    <Modal
                                        show={this.state.visible}
                                      onHide={this.handleClose}
                                    >
                                            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                                <Modal.Title>Run Stuff for Stuff</Modal.Title>
                                            </Modal.Header>
                                            <Modal.Body>
                                                <div>{dt.lotsofstuff}</div>
                                            </Modal.Body>
                                            <Modal.Footer>
                                                <Button
                                                    variant="secondary"
                                                    onClick={this.handleClose}
                                                >
                                                    Close
                        </Button>
                                                <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                                                    Download
                        </Button>
                                            </Modal.Footer>
                                    </Modal>                                  
                                </tr>                               
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div> 
            </div>
        ) :
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <p>No Data to Display at the moment</p>
                </div>
            </div>;
        }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {



    return {

    };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({    
    getstuff: () => dispatch(myActions.getstuff())
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(myLoad);
```

Comment: Can you click on the error and see what line of code is throwing it?  My guess is it's in react-bootstrap somewhere...

Comment: The error is here: this.setState within the componentDidMount

Comment: If I remove the modal portion the issue goes away. However, I am not sure what would be conflicting with the modal aspect.

Comment: Seems there is some issues with certain Chrome versions https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3620

Comment: FDunny enough, I do a majority of my testing in chrome.

Comment: I tried their solution but was not successful.